# CLOB TO BLOB and parse to APEX table

Tags: oracle, parsing, oracle-apex, procedure, oracle-apex-5.1

So i have a procedure using SOAP function
and i want to parse the data into the table...but when i run the script it cameback with
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttdII.png)
here is my procedure script i'm still new using apex...

```
create or replace procedure       "GET_SUPL"
(p_wsdl IN VARCHAR2,
p_version IN VARCHAR2,
p_username IN VARCHAR2,
p_password IN VARCHAR2,
p_wallet_path IN VARCHAR2 default null,
p_wallet_pwd IN VARCHAR2 default null,
p_rpt_path IN VARCHAR2,
p_rpt_name IN VARCHAR2,
r_out_id OUT NUMBER,
l_output OUT BLOB)
IS
l_envelope   CLOB;
l_result     XMLTYPE;
l_base64     CLOB;
\--        l_output     CLOB;
v_out_id     NUMBER;
v_sqlerrm    VARCHAR2 (4000);
v_name varchar2(100);
begin
/\*
insert into TG_OUTPUT_EXTERNAL_RPT (RPT_NAME, START_DATE_DOWNLOAD, STATUS_DOWNLOAD)
values (p_rpt_name, sysdate, 'P')
returning OUT_ID
into v_out_id;
\*/

        /* 20190219/Aan/Case dimana saat insert gagal return ID. */
        
       -- COMMIT;
    
        
       -- r_out_id := v_out_id;
    
        /* 20190205/Aan/ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: invalid LOB locator specified: ORA-22275 */
        DBMS_LOB.createtemporary (l_envelope, TRUE);
        DBMS_LOB.createtemporary (l_base64, TRUE);

\--        DBMS_LOB.createtemporary (l_output, TRUE);

        l_envelope :=
            '
           <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:pub="http://xmlns.oracle.com/oxp/service/PublicReportService">

\<soap:Header/\>
\<soap:Body\>
\<pub:runReport\>
\<pub:reportRequest\>
\<pub:attributeFormat\>csv\</pub:attributeFormat\>
\<!-- Flatten XML should always be false when we have XML type of output to display the XML tags as mentioned in BIP Data Model and display XML structure in as expected format --\>
\<pub:flattenXML\>false\</pub:flattenXML\>
\<pub:parameterNameValues\>

            </pub:parameterNameValues>
            <pub:reportAbsolutePath>/Custom/-------/--------------</pub:reportAbsolutePath>
            <!-- Setting sizeOfDataChunkDownload to -1 will return the output to the calling client -->
            <pub:sizeOfDataChunkDownload>-1</pub:sizeOfDataChunkDownload>
         </pub:reportRequest>
      </pub:runReport>

\</soap:Body\>
\</soap:Envelope\>
';

        l_result :=
            APEX_WEB_SERVICE.make_request (
                p_url                => XXXXXX,
                p_version            => '1.2',
                p_envelope           => l_envelope,
                p_username           => 'XXXXXXX',
                p_password           => 'XXXXXXX',
                p_transfer_timeout   => 720,
                p_wallet_path        => null,
                p_wallet_pwd         => null);
    
        l_base64 :=
            APEX_WEB_SERVICE.parse_xml_clob (
                p_xml   => l_result,
                p_xpath   =>
                    ' //ns2:runReportResponse/ns2:runReportReturn/ns2:reportBytes/text()',
                p_ns    =>
                    ' xmlns:ns2="http://xmlns.oracle.com/oxp/service/PublicReportService"');
    
        l_output :=
                APEX_WEB_SERVICE.clobbase642blob (
                    REPLACE (REPLACE (l_base64, CHR (10), NULL),
                             CHR (13),
                             NULL));
    
         dbms_lob.createtemporary(  l_output,true );
        COMMIT;
    
        DBMS_LOB.freetemporary (l_envelope);
        DBMS_LOB.freetemporary (l_base64);

select  col001
from table(
APEX_DATA_PARSER.parse(
p_content         => l_output,
p_file_name       => 'test.csv') ) ;

\--            dbms_output.put_line(col001);
\--        DBMS_LOB.freetemporary (l_output);
DBMS_LOB.freetemporary (l_envelope);
DBMS_LOB.freetemporary (l_base64);
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS
THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (SQLERRM);

            v_sqlerrm := SUBSTR (SQLERRM, 1, 4000);
            COMMIT;
    
        INSERT INTO TEST_SUPL values(v_name);
    
            COMMIT;

end;
```

This is my current procedure that i create, and i'm stuck figuring this out

I hope i can get a better version of this script or maybe a solution for my problem

Comment: =\> is not a valid syntax. Replace it with =>

Comment: ahh yeah sorry, idk why itu turns into =\> when i copied to the website, i already fix the typos but still get the same error